# Share post of react-native app to third party app instagram using native module

Tags: objective-c, reactjs, react-native, instagram

Please pardon if it is duplicate. I'm developing an app which shares it's post in third party-instagram app using react-native. I searched everywhere and found that there is no such feature available for react-native but it is available in native-ios and native-android. I'm trying to implement in native-ios(objective-c) and found lots of codes for that but I'm little bit confused and can't develop my functionality. Can anyone please explain it step by step here? I've done with linking native-ios files with react-native by doing below code.

**.h file**

```
#ifndef Instashare_h
#define Instashare_h

#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface Instashare : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end

#endif /* Instashare_h */
```

**.m file**

```
#import "Instashare.h"=
#import "React/RCTLog.h"

@implementation Instashare

// This RCT (React) "macro" exposes the current module to JavaScript
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

// We must explicitly expose methods otherwise JavaScript can't access anything
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(get)
{
   NSLog(@"explanation code here");
}

@end
```

**React-native.js file**

```
var InstagramShare = NativeModules.Instashare;

export default class ShareComponents extends PureComponent {
  _handleInsta = () => {
     InstagramShare.get();
  }
  render{
     return(
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this._handleInsta()}
        >
          <Text>Instagram</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A native module is just an Objective-C class that implements the `RCTBridgeModule` protocol. If you are wondering, **RCT** is an abbreviation of **ReaCT**.

```
// Instashare.h
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface Instashare : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

React Native will not expose any methods of **Instashare** to JavaScript unless explicitly told to. This is done using the `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD()` macro:

```
#import "Instashare.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation Instashare

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(get:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
  NSLog(@"explanation code here");
}

@end
```

**Usage**

```js
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
var Instashare = NativeModules.Instashare;
Instashare.get();
```

Comment: thank you Hong for correction can you please explain how to develop native code?

Comment: Please refer to the official document https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios